# Why is my sidebar not positioned where it should be?

Tags: html, css

I want to turn the "aside" tag into a sidebar, but i can't make it nested onto the right side next to the two articles. I don't get why is the "sidebar" stuck on the bottom and not getting on top of the page? How do i nest it there? Why is it not getting nested now? First i thought it's because the width of the two articles is not allowing it to climb on top of the page, but then i reduced the width and it's not climbing up there. Why?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 150px;
  color: black;
  text-align: ;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: OCR A Stf, monospace;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
}

article {
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

article h2 {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  background-color: ;
  width: ;
  margin: ;
  padding: 30px 30px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.general-info ol {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.general-info li {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  height: ;
  float: right;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="new-wc3.html">Cities of the world</a>
</header>

<div id="main">

  <nav>

    <a href="new york page.html">New York City</a>
    <a href="#2">Los Angeles</a>
    <a href="#3">Chicago</a>
    <a href="#4">Boston</a>
    <a href="#5">Tokyo</a>
    <a href="#6">Osaka</a>
    <a href="#7">Seoul</a>
    <a href="#8">Beijing</a>
    <a href="#9">Shanghai</a>
    <a href="#10">Hong Kong</a>
    <a href="#11">Sydney</a>
    <a href="#12">Moscow</a>
    <a href="#13">Berlin</a>
    <a href="#14">Paris</a>
    <a href="#15">London</a>
    <a href="#16">Rome</a>

  </nav>


  <main>

    <article class="pics">

      <h2>Please select a city.</h2>


    </article>

    <article class="general-info">

      <h2>Please select a city.</h2>

      <p>
        </h2>
        <p>
          </h2>
          <p>
            </h2>

    </article>

    <div class="sidebar">
      <aside>

        <p>This should be a sidebar</p>

      </aside>

    </div>


  </main>


  <footer>

    <p>Copyright &copy; 2020, Cities of the World</p>

  </footer>
```

Comment: You should fix the HTML errors: `<p>
        </h2>
        <p>
          </h2>
          <p>
            </h2>` In your `.general-info` article. That is invalid HTML.

Comment: Fixed it. But it didn't effect the sidebar.

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: @TaishoMori It's ok to have questions about the positioning concepts, but expanding your question in comments is not a good way to deal with it. So in order to get proper answers to your questions, you should update your current question and totally describe your current issue and situation that you dealing with. So I will delete my answer for now and will wait for you to update your question properly. You can read more about how to ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a need to change the structure of the html.Write the code of sidebar before the code of articles.If you need something else, please let me know.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 150px;
  color: black;
  text-align: ;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: OCR A Stf, monospace;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
}

article {
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

article h2 {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  background-color: ;
  width: ;
  margin: ;
  padding: 30px 30px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.general-info ol {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.general-info li {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  height: ;
  float: right;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="new-wc3.html">Cities of the world</a>
</header>

<div id="main">

  <nav>

    <a href="new york page.html">New York City</a>
    <a href="#2">Los Angeles</a>
    <a href="#3">Chicago</a>
    <a href="#4">Boston</a>
    <a href="#5">Tokyo</a>
    <a href="#6">Osaka</a>
    <a href="#7">Seoul</a>
    <a href="#8">Beijing</a>
    <a href="#9">Shanghai</a>
    <a href="#10">Hong Kong</a>
    <a href="#11">Sydney</a>
    <a href="#12">Moscow</a>
    <a href="#13">Berlin</a>
    <a href="#14">Paris</a>
    <a href="#15">London</a>
    <a href="#16">Rome</a>

  </nav>


  <main>

 <div class="sidebar">
      <aside>

        <p>This should be a sidebar</p>

      </aside>

    </div>
    <article class="pics">

      <h2>Please select a city.</h2>


    </article>

    <article class="general-info">

      <h2>Please select a city.</h2>

      <p>
        </h2>
        <p>
          </h2>
          <p>
            </h2>

    </article>


  </main>


  <footer>

    <p>Copyright &copy; 2020, Cities of the World</p>

  </footer>
```

Comment: So, the only reason the sidebar wasn't nested right of the two articles is because the div code should've been placed first before the article code?

Comment: Yeah, the structure of HTML code defines that.Also, If you like my answer, please accept it as answer :).